# Intellisense and Autocompletion Unity

Tags: c#, unity-container

I am playing with the IoC Container Unity, and according to the documentation, adding this xmlns attribute to the "unity" section must allow Visual Studio doing some Intellisense stuff :

```
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="unity" type="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.UnityConfigurationSection, Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration"/>
    </configSections>
    [..]
    <unity xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/practices/2010/unity">
        [..]
    </unity>
</configuration>
```

Actually, it doesn't work. It seems the resource has been (re?)moved. Do you know the new link ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The actual xsd file can be found here: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/unitycontainer/configuration/master/src/Unity.Configuration.xsd

Comment: Thanks ! I am not playing with Unity anymore, but I hope it will help some people !

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're talking about this link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn507436(v=pandp.30).aspx

Comment: Yes I'm talking about this. But the XSD is not in the Visual Studio list. I need to add it manually ? How ? I can't find it.

Comment: @user9993 I will too :)