# Unity Intellisense doesn't work(Miscellaneous Files issue)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I am having the issue with visual studio not recognizing the C# file, I have checked the Preferences and no problem there it is still set on visual studio (I use visual studio 2019) furthermore, scripts that are imported from the Package manager work just fine but when I create a new C# script or use ones I made before (before visual studio didn't recognize them in the same project) I get the Miscellaneous Files.

Comment: Automatically list members was already checked, I also made sure everything was up to date and that I had imported Visual studio editor in my package manager but i still have this issue

Comment: Ok, I found my problem, in the Solution Explorer, there was a file named "Assembly-CSharp (Unloaded)" so I just had to right-click and load.

Answer (score 0):

Solution for IntelliSense not available.

One of the visual studio settings is not checked: Tools - Options - Text Editor - C#. Check "Automatically list members".

Reference link:

[Unity Intellisense doesn't work(Solution1, Miscellaneous Files issue)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64544973/unity-intellisense-doesnt-worksolution1-miscellaneous-files-issue)

[Visual Studio Intellisense for UnityEngine not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61016357/visual-studio-intellisense-for-unityengine-not-working)

[Intellisense and Autocompletion Unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25442776/intellisense-and-autocompletion-unity)

Hope it helps you.